# Do duplicate questions count as "well-received" for the Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic badges?

Tags: support, questions, badges, duplicate-questions

Do questions marked as duplicate, even with a positive score, count for badges that need *well-received* questions?

For example, if I had 5 questions with a positive score in 5 different days, but one of them is marked as a duplicate, would I earn the Curious Badge?

Comment: All questions count towards or against your ability.  Questions that have a positive count towards your ability.  Specifics of the system are not known, in order to avoid, the system from being abused. So how they are weighted is not known by the community.

Comment: *A well-received question is one that's **open**, not deleted, and has a score > 0.*

Comment: The implication here is that duplicate counts as _closed_.

Answer (score 4):

From [**the FAQ**](/a/67399/350567):

> Any **open** question that is not deleted and has a score >= 1 is considered *well-received*

Technically, duplicate questions count as "closed" (they show up when you search `closed:1`, as well as in Close Vote queues), so they don't count as "well-received".

[Try the search on Meta Stack Exchange](/search?tab=votes&q=closed%3A1) and you'll see the 1st result is a question closed as duplicate.

Comment: In revision 103 (https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/67399/revisions#) this text was edited.